# Could not load type System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Could not load type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters' from assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=6.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

I am using OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions class for token authentication. One another package uses system.identity.Model ver 6. Now once I am taking the latest of another package my startup class code started throwing errors.